# bootstrap3 different button size for mobile than for screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible with BootStrap3 to have the button be `btn-block` on mobile and `btn` on non-mobile?
If so, how, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .btn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Using two buttons is not a particularly good practice. That's not DRY or accessible.  Media queries are designed specifically for this purpose: to be able to allow you to change style properties based on the size of the viewport.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of writing custom styles—like other answers will suggest and will also be a pain to maintain—you can instead use Bootstrap 3’s built-in [responsive utility](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) classes.

First, define what “mobile” is. Personally, mobile is a bad way to group classes as some phones have such high-density displays that they can have screen sizes in thousands of pixels. That’s what Bootstrap refer to break points as small, medium, large and not mobile, tablet and desktop any more.

Once you’ve defined the breakpoint you want to target, you can then do something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary visible-xs-block visible-sm-block">Button Text</button>
```

The classes to pay attention to are **.visible-xs-block** and  **.visible-sm-block**. These will make the button block-level at the “xs” and “sm” breakpoints.

Comment: indeed it does become invisible for `md` and larger breakpoints

Comment: Then apply the **.visible-md** and **.visible-lg** classes.

Comment: I believe .visible-md will apply to large devices automatically so technically speaking, the .visible-lg isn't required but would be good human readability.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can easly use this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn hidden-xs">Button Text</button>
<button type="button" class="btn-block hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">Button Text</button>
```

The second button will show on mobile devices and the first button will show on any other devices like tablet, small desktop or large desktop.

Answer (score 0):

With BS 4+ you can :

```
// All .btn are like .btn-sm if screen is sm or xs
@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
  .btn {
    @include button-size($input-btn-padding-y-sm, $input-btn-padding-x-sm, $font-size-sm, $line-height-sm, $btn-border-radius-sm);
  }
}
```